# Understanding Teamcity and CVS

Tags: eclipse, build, branch, cvs, teamcity

I have a couple of questions about CVS and teamcity that is troubling me

1. How is CVS and teamcity connected? When Something is committed to the trunk. How does teamcity pick these changes up and perform a build.
2. In our trunk in CVS we have a branch (say Branch1) thats has lots of projects (say project1, project2, project3, project4). I want to have another branch  (say Branch2) which comes off branch1 that just has project4 on it. Project4 won't be on branch1 any more. So if I want project4 I check it out from branch2.
3. Once I have created this branch can I configure it with teamcity?

If you could answer any of the questions that would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teamcity is fairly well documented.  You can find all the details on CVS here:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/CVS

For the most part all VCS root configuration is similar so this is the general documentations:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Configuring+VCS+Settings

I'm assuming version 6.x here but you can find docs for any version you need.

Teamcity has a plugin for each VCS system (Git, SVN, CVS, etc.) in general it just polls the VCS for changes and if there are changes it checks them out and builds them.

You can configure any branch to be "watched" by a build, even multiple branches, but it won't pick up and build new branches automatically, you have to add them (see the documentation above).

Comment: Thanks for answer. That is helpful. I'll look at the documentation :) Another question that leads on from 2. How easy is it to just have project4 in its own branch and removed from the other branch?

At the moment It is:

Branch1 - Project1, Project2, Project3, Project4

but I want:
Branch1 - Project1, Project2, Project3
Branch2 - Project4

Comment: I really couldn't tell you I don't really use CVS myself, few people do really it's a pretty outdated VCS system.  Is this a legacy situation or are you just setting this up?  If it's new stuff I'd look into using Git instead.